# Alternative way to write this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Firstly, I'm using d3.js and SVG. I've got this piece of code that draws a path:

```
var one = d3.select('#canvas1');
var oneCanvas = one.append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 190);
oneCanvas.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M100 15 A 55 55, 0, 0, 0, 73 61 A 55 55, 0, 0, 1, 127 61 A 64 64, 0, 0, 0, 100 15")
        .style("stroke","black")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .on("click", function(){
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "magenta");
            alert("You've clicked on the path in the 1st div");
        });
```

I use the path about 20 times throughout. With this approach, I repeat the above code time and again as shown in https://jsfiddle.net/s26kghmq/

The reason I don't use `'d3.selectAll'` is that by doing so I won't be able to set different functions when the path is clicked.

I implemented svg's `'def'` and `'use'`, but that doesn't help me either because if I've set a style previously, I can't override it again in the `'use'` as discussed here: http://taye.me/blog/svg/a-guide-to-svg-use-elements/

I was wondering if there's an alternative approach to achieve the functionality without the repetition?

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the callback differs in the `.on` event, there are many ways to handle that.  `d3` is all about data-binding, iteration and **not** duplicating code.  So, you really, really should be using `selectAll`.

```js
var data = [1,2];

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(['magenta','yellow']);

var one = d3.selectAll('.v1')
  .data(data)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 190)
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M100 15 A 55 55, 0, 0, 0, 73 61 A 55 55, 0, 0, 1, 127 61 A 64 64, 0, 0, 0, 100 15")
  .style("stroke","black")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", 1)
  .on('click', function(d){
    d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d));
    alert("You've clicked on the path in the " + d + " div");
  });
```

```css
.v1{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

#canvas2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas1" class="v1"></div>

<div id="canvas2" class="v1"></div>
```

---

**Updates for comments**

If the callbacks are unique *per datum* then they too just become attributes of the data.  Further, you can always segment out shared and specific functionality:

```js
function sharedFunc(elem,d){
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(elem).style('fill', d.color);
}

var data = [
  {
    specificFunc: function(d){
       alert("you've clicked the 1st one");
    },
    color: 'magenta'
  },{
    specificFunc: function(d){
       alert("you've clicked the 2nd one");
    },
    color: 'yellow'
  }
];

d3.selectAll('.v1')
  .data(data)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 190)
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M100 15 A 55 55, 0, 0, 0, 73 61 A 55 55, 0, 0, 1, 127 61 A 64 64, 0, 0, 0, 100 15")
  .style("stroke","black")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", 1)
  .on('click', function(d){
    sharedFunc(this, d);
    d.specificFunc(d);
  }); 

$("#canvas1").click(function(){
    alert("you clicked on the canvas");
});
```

```css
.v1{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

.v2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
}

#canvas2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas1" class="v1"></div>
<div id="canvas2" class="v1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But what if I had functions defined like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s26kghmq/2/ ? I've edited the code your way to show the result. It will ultimately lead to duplication as I've shown in the updated fiddle? :) Unless I'm missing out on something...

Comment: Perfect! Learnt a lot with this one question. Thank you!

Comment: @nicki, you are welcome.  I should have added in my answer, that `d3` is **d**ata **d**riven **d**ocuments, it's all about data dictating the rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the path drawing in a separate function as such

```
var drawPath = function(ele, clickFunction){
    ele.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M100 15 A 55 55, 0, 0, 0, 73 61 A 55 55, 0, 0, 1, 127 61 A 64 64, 0, 0, 0, 100 15")
        .style("stroke","black")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .on("click", clickFunction)
}
```

and then reuse this function like this:

```
oneCanvas.call(drawPath, yourSpecificClickFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like it should solve my problem, but I can't get it to work. Maybe I'm missing out on something? Can you please update the fiddle? :)

Comment: I've made a fiddle containing my changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/b3q93sea/ although Marks answer is also perfectly fine